# Access Json object : Twig

Tags: json, twitter, symfony

I have passed  a JSON object to my twig template in symfony2, then i have assigned the object to JavaScript variable.

My object is like

`[{&quot;data&quot;:&quot;{&quot;params&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:&quot;98&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:&quot;101&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:&quot;151&quot;,&quot;y&quot; ....`

Now when i alert the object it shows the above object`array()` which is OK, but when i alert object.data it shows nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Use `console.log` in Firebug - it really helps to debug things...

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you solved your problem. 
I have the same trouble, but this worked for me

```
# your_template.html.twig
<script type="text/javascript">
{% autoescape false %}
    var your_variable = {{ var_from_controller }};
{% endautoescape %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

twig automatically escape the string before printing it.
You have to use twig raw filter.

{{ yourVarWithJson | raw }}

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a JSON representation, if you want to use it as a Javascript object, you first need to either pass it through the "eval" function or use some sort of JSON parser. For more information, see this link: http://www.json.org/js.html